# File path from java to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, json, eval

My code returns a JSON as String from java to javascript where the JSON  must be evaluated to an object with `eval`.
The JSON contains path `c:\tmp\prove` like:

```
[
    {
        "command": "LoadFromCSV",
        "params": {
            "folderName": "c:\tmp\prove",
            "fileName": "NewLinesSaved.txt"
        }
    }
]
```

As written the JSON must be interpreted with `eval`. ATM the best way i found in Java to translate so that `eval` works is:

```
String tmpJson = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(jsonString);
tmpJson = tmpJson.replace("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
```

The result in the page is

```
var spip = "[\r\n{\"command\":\"LoadFromCSV\", \"params\":{\"folderName\":\"c:\\\\tmp\\\\prove\\\\\", \"fileName\":\"NewLinesSaved.txt\"}}]"
```

It works perfectly, but the translation algorithm smells a bit.
Is there a better way that I missed?

EDIT: I switched from `eval` to `JSON.parse`, they both works, the question remains

Comment: Who uses eval in JavaScript for JSON? How are you returning the string/generating the JSON in JAVA?

Comment: That JSON string is invalid. folderName should be `"\\c:\\tmp\\prove"`. So something is definitely wrong.

Comment: @epascarello in the JSP there is: var jpip = eval(spip);

Comment: And we have not been using eval for JSON since IE7. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse is what you should be using and is safer than eval

Comment: The result in the jsp page is: var spip = `[\r\n{\"command\":\"LoadFromCSV\", \"params\":{\"folderName\":\"c:\\\\tmp\\\\prove\\\\\", \"fileName\":\"NewLinesSaved.txt\"}},\r\n{\"command\":\"SaveToCSV\", \"params\":{\"folderName\":\"c:\\\\tmp\\\\prove\\\\\", \"fileName\":\"OUT.txt\"}}\r\n]`;
        //var jpip = JSON.parse(spip);
        var jpip = eval(spip);

Comment: Thx i changed to JSON.parse, but the transation method is the same